# What is the purpose of observers within a war cabinet?

Tags: armed-conflict, government, israel

> During the 2023 Israel–Hamas War, Prime Minister Benjamin Netanyahu
> announced a war cabinet of the following composition.[40][41]
>
> 3 full members:
>
> Prime Minister Benjamin Netanyahu
>
> Minister of Defense Yoav Gallant
>
> Minister without portfolio and former Chief of the General Staff Benny Gantz
>
> and 2 observers:
>
> Minister of Strategic Affairs Ron Dermer
>
> Minister without portfolio and former Chief of the General Staff Gadi Eizenkot

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_cabinet

What is the purpose of observers within a war cabinet? Israel created a war cabinet, but interestingly, it's the only war cabinet that had observers looking at the Wikipedia article, so I was wondering what the purpose of observers might be within the context of a war cabinet. Are they used for the purpose of ensuring more transparency?

Comment: Quite probably a question of the proportion of party factions represented. Netanyahu and Gallant: Likud, Gantz: National Unity; Dermer: Likud, Eizenkot: National Unity.